# Delete users comments with PHP SDK and GRAPH API

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I'm using PHP SDK and Graph API to delete some users comments from my page. I do this in two steps :
1. fetch comments ID-s
2. delete comments using comment-id and page token ('/'.$comment_id.'?access_token='.$token, 'DELETE')
Problem is that comments didn't really deleted, but hidden.
Is there way to really delete users comments